# How to search a text inside messages in a topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to check if messages containing a certain event id are available in a certain kafka topic.

How can I do this from command line?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Kafka cli tool for searching events. You'd need to pipe existing console consumer command to `grep`